# Converting numerics with different length (day = 1-31) to date-format

Tags: r, date-conversion

Hey awesome community,

so I got this pretty big dataset and unfortunately the date columns is in the following format:

```
20112016
28112016
2122016
6122016
11122016
```

Its a simple numeric format. How can i transfer it to standard dates format like 02-12-2016.

```
betterDates <-as.Date(as.character(betterDates), "%e%m%Y")
```

Comment: format should be `%d%m%Y` - i.e. `as.Date('20112016', '%d%m%Y')`

Comment: @Sotos `as.Date("6122016", format="%d%m%Y")` gives `NA`.

Comment: @thelatemail did not notice that. I guess `sprintf` should take care of that - i.e. `as.Date(sprintf('%08d', 6122016), '%d%m%Y')`

Answer (score 2):

The format of days/months need to be the same with 2 digits, giving a total of 8 digits for each date. In case where day is 1 or 2 or... or 9, we can use `sprintf` to make them 01, 02, ..., 09, i.e.

```
x <-c(20112016, 28112016, 2122016, 6122016, 11122016)

as.Date(sprintf('%08d', x), '%d%m%Y')
#[1] "2016-11-20" "2016-11-28" "2016-12-02" "2016-12-06" "2016-12-11"
```

Comment: Thank you for that response! It works very well for one of the date-colums. However, there are two others in the same format, where it gives me a NA for all values... Since there +1000000 people its hard to find the reason... But all of them are in format mentioned above. Is there any other way of doing this? 

The sprintf() does this in the columns: 00000484

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package is pretty handy in these situations:

```
x <-c(20112016, 28112016, 2122016, 6122016, 11122016)
lubridate::dmy(x)
```

> ```
> [1] "2016-11-20" "2016-11-28" "2016-12-02" "2016-12-06" "2016-12-11"
> ```